# Accessing minizinc data from Python

Tags: python, minizinc

I'm using the Python interface to Minizinc and read both model (.mzn) and data (.dzn) from external files. Is there a way to access problem data from Python?

As example I use cakes2-model from Minizinc manual, which has a decision variable *b* and a data field *flour*.

```
    from minizinc import Instance, Model, Solver
    solverToUse = "coinbc"
    solver = Solver.lookup(solverToUse)
    print(solver.name, ",", solver.version)
    model = Model("cakes2.mzn")
    model.add_file("cakes2.dzn")
    instance = Instance(solver, model)
    print(instance.method)
    result=instance.solve()
    b = result.solution.b
    print(b)
```

This runs fine. But how can I access the data/parameter *flour*? Below is result when interactively asking for data in the same way as for decision variables:

```
C:\Users\MartinJo>python -i callingMinizinc2.py
COIN-BC , 2.10.5/1.17.5
Method.MAXIMIZE
3
>>> result.solution.b
3
>>> result.solution.flour
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Solution' object has no attribute 'flour'
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MiniZinc Python interface is currently an interface that communicates using the `minizinc` executable. By default, MiniZinc does doesn't provide any information about its parameter variable in the solution output. There are two solutions to the problem.

- If you can change the model and no Python code before solving depend on the data, then you can add `::add_to_output` annotations to both the decision variables and parameter variables that you are interesting in. This way `result.solution.flour` will be available.
- Alternatively, MiniZinc Python has its own DZN parser. This can be enabled by installing the package as `pip install minizinc[dzn]`, and then including your data file with the `parse_data` flag set to `True`. In your example `model.add_file("cakes2.dzn", parse_data=True)`. Afterwards the data will be available by index of the `Model` object: `model["flour"]`.